# Change the image in the list according to time in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I put some pictures in the list.
As time goes by, the list index increases, so I hope these pictures change.
But I hope the game ends when the index of the list grows to the end.
I want to turn the index back to zero so that the game ends right away.
But error messages keep popping up like this.

> ```
> self.image = self.images[self.index]
> IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

```py
class AnimatedSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, position):

        super(AnimatedSprite, self).__init__()
        size = (68, 75)

        images = []
        images.append(pygame.image.load('IMG/DinoRun1.png'))
        images.append(pygame.image.load('IMG/DinoRun2.png'))
        images.append(pygame.image.load('IMG/DinoJump.png'))
        images.append(pygame.image.load('IMG/DinoDuck1.png'))
        images.append(pygame.image.load('IMG/DinoDuck2.png'))

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(position, size)
        self.images = [pygame.transform.scale(image, size) for image in images]

        self.index = 0
        self.image = images[self.index]

        self.animation_time = 1
        self.current_time = 0

    def update(self, mt):
        self.current_time += mt

        if self.current_time >= self.animation_time:
            self.current_time = 0

            self.index += 1
            if self.index == len(self.images):
                done = True
                run = False
            if self.index > len(self.images):
                self.index = 0


            self.image = self.images[self.index]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1:

You need to check whether `self.index` is greater than or equal to `len(self.images)`. The valid indices of a list of length 5 are 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4:

```py
if self.index >= len(self.images):
    self.index = 0
```

---

Solution 2:

If you want to show the last image for a longer period, you need to clamp the index when you get  it form the list:

```py
self.image = self.images[min(self.index, len(self.images) - 1)]
```

Comment: For solution 1 one can use modulus `self.index % self.images`

Comment: @MSH No. He wants to end the game if `self.index == len(self.images)`, o the index has to be increased to `len (self.images)`.

Comment: Yep you are right. I think I forgot that point.

Comment: This should work and is good. A more advanced (more pythonic?) solution would be use a generator function to yield the images.

Comment: @Alan This is a beginner question. I do not want to confuse him. Anyway, he asked about the flaw in his method and not about a redesign.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, that's why I said it was good. It's also important for future reference that people are aware that as skill progresses there are other ways this should be done.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But if I turn the index back to zero such as solution 1, the pictures on the list keep going back. I solved the problem with pygame.quit() and exit()! There's another problem here. I want the game over message to come out and the game to end. I made a function that outputs game over text and put it under this if statement, but it didn't work and only the game ended. I checked that the text function works without a problem, so what is the problem?